# How to multiple fetch data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I try to fetch data in table condition then I want to select If in member condition table have condition_id I want to print out success_img else print unsuccess  I've already try

condition

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id .           |      name        |  success_img     | unsuccess_img
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     name1 .      |   success        | unsuccess
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

member condition

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id .           |  condition_id    |  member_id       | add_by
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     1 .   .      |   1 .            | admin
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Here is my html

```
<?php foreach ($data['getCoin'] as $item) { ?>
        <div class="skill-need-inner">
           <div class="skill-need-img">
            <?php 
            if ( !empty($data['condition_id'])) {
                if (in_array($item['condition_id'],$data['condition_id'])) {
            ?>
                    <img class="" src="<?php echo assets('uploads/'.$item['success']); ?>" alt="scucess" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<?php echo $data['add_by']; ?>">
            <?php
                }  else {
            ?>
                    <img class="" src="<?php echo assets('uploads/'.$item['unsuccess']); ?>" alt="unsuccess" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" >
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is my Controller

```
 $data['getCoin'] = test::getInstance()->getCoin();
        $data['getCoinSuccess'] = test::getInstance()->getCoinSuccess(Session::get('member_id'));
        if ($data['getCoinSuccess']) {
            foreach ($data['getCoinSuccess'] as $itemSuccess) {
                $data['condition_id'][] = $itemSuccess['condition_id'];
                $data['add_by'][] = $itemSuccess['add_by'];
            }
        }
```

my Models test

```
public function getCoin(){
    $sql = 'SELECT * from `'CONDITION'` ORDER BY `condition_id` DESC';
    return $this->query_rows( $sql );
}

public function getCoinSuccess($id){
    $sql = 'SELECT * from `'.MEMBER_CONDITION.'`
     WHERE member_id = '.$id;
    return $this->query_rows( $sql );
}
```

In my try It's print out only img success but How can i print out add_by too ? Now i'm thinking about join table. I know my logic not good .Im beginner sorry about that

Comment: use `inner join`

Comment: thank you i'll try it @prakashtank

Comment: Also have a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn about prepared statements and how to use them to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: thank you i'll look into it ! @Twinfriends

Comment: is their any example same as my question pls

Answer (score 0):

I think following query will work for you

```
SELECT * FROM member_condition 
INNER JOIN condition 
ON member_condition.condition_id = condition.id 
ORDER BY member_condition.condition_id DESC
```

Comment: I already try this but I want to printint out all condition first 
then check if have condition in condition_member echo img success
 In inner join it didnt print all condition